# Find number of distinct values in array with a limited space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given a very large array, allocated on the **HDD** = { 1, 1, 5, 7, 8, 1, 6, 10, 20, 1 } we need to find out how many distinct values exist. the solution for the mentioned array is 7, 7 distinct numbers in total{ 1, 5, 6, 7, 6, 10, 20}. there is no need to save the numbers.

some hints that were given, I need to work both on the HDD and on the RAM. but, HDD is significantly larger than the RAM. so holding hash tables, and linked-lists isn't possible when all values are distinct. from my understanding, i need to allocate K constant fixed size arrays(m elements each). after that, i need to fill all k arrays, sort each an one of them. and then compare them and count the distinct parts and fill them once again until im done with all the values allocated on the HDD. My problem is with the last part, what exactly do i need to do once the arrays are sorted?

**Edit**: rutime example, HDD may contain 10^10 records, RAM may hold only 10^5,
and K = 10, M = 10. for each array handled, there is a need to read the next M values to that specific array.

there should be only one counter, stating number of different values. biggest number may be N

thanks

Comment: Can numbers be arbitrarily big?

Comment: problem was originally presented with strings, for the given solution, lets say the biggest number can be 100

Comment: If it's any string, Bloom filters might help, but if the number of possible values is small, the answer is simple, just create a bit field of 100 bits and set the bit corresponding to that value.

Comment: @biziclop - i somehow need to use these K constant arrays each iteration, not sure how.

Comment: Is it possible to write back to HDD? Can you do an external merge sort?

Comment: from my understanding, you shouldn't re-write to the HDD

Comment: In that case just do an external merge sort, then you have the entire sorted collection in HDD. You might not be able to hold unique items in memory, so you might have to erase duplicates in HDD instead.

Comment: "the biggest number can be 100" - use 100 counters.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Or just 1 100 bit counter. But clearly the assignment requires a different solution.

Comment: that comment is part of the assignment... we need clarification.

Comment: You're looking for an exact or approximate count-distinct?  How big are the numbers involved?  How many of them are there?

Comment: If all of the items can be distinct (i.e. no duplicates), and the items can't all fit into memory, then there is no way you can do this without writing temporary information to the disk or some other external storage. The standard answer to your question is to use an external merge sort. Your comments alternately make the problem trivially simple, and impossible to solve. You need to refine your requirements. As written, taking comments into account, your question has no answer.

Comment: @JimMischel: "the items can't all fit into memory, then there is no way you can do this without writing temporary information to the disk or some other external storage" - that's not true, you can do it in multiple passes (processing numbers between 1-100, 101-200, ...)

Comment: Try to hold in RAM a dictionary of the count of every encountered number.  When the number of keys become too big, flush the least frequents keys and dump them in a temporary file.

Comment: @Seb: "least frequents keys" - it's totally irrelevant how frequent they are. I think you misunderstood the task.

Comment: *"The keys with the smallest occurence count"  The objective is to reduce the size of the original file successively focusing on the values with more occurrences

Comment: @seb: basically you repeated yourself, and it still doesn't make any sense. why do care about occurence count?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: True enough, assuming that there is some upper limit on the value of a number. It'll just take a really long time because you have to make many passes over the file. And whereas that will work for numbers, it certainly won't work for strings.

Comment: @JimMischel: strings are nothing more than a series of numbers. in fact, anything, that can be serialized can be treated as a number. now this one will really take a long time.. :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yes, I know that. But a 20-character string is a 160-bit number. Using the binning technique you're talking about, in the general case it would take essentially forever for the program to complete if there were many strings. As far as I'm concerned, "taking forever" and "impossible" are the same thing.

Comment: Guys, you're missing the point, the answer shouldn't be dependent on input length

Comment: @Seb, the objectives are to find number of distinct values within the array, there is no need of altering the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. I defined 2 vectors, first vector to represent the Hdd data, and another vector to represent offsets within the Hdd vector.

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <direct.h>

    #define FILE_NAME "\\data.txt"
    #define ROWS        10
    #define MAX_LINE    100
    #define ARRSIZE(arr) sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])

    class CPair
    {
    public:
        CPair(__int64 nOffset) : m_llOffset(nOffset), m_llCurOffset(nOffset), m_bChecked(0)
        { }

        __int64 m_llOffset;
        __int64 m_llCurOffset;
        bool    m_bChecked;
    };

    std::vector<long>       vecHDD;
    std::vector<CPair>  vecOffsets;

    long RetrieveValueFromHDD(__int64& i64Offset)
    {
        return vecHDD[(long)i64Offset];
    }

    void FindDistinct()
    {
        // calculate how many fragments within the HDD we've got
        long nFragments = (vecHDD.size() / ROWS);
        long nCount     = 0;

        while(nFragments > 0)
        {
            long nMinimum = INT_MAX;
            for(int i = 0; i < (int)vecOffsets.size(); i++)
            { // find the minimum number
                if((false == vecOffsets[i].m_bChecked) && (RetrieveValueFromHDD(vecOffsets[i].m_llCurOffset) < nMinimum))
                    nMinimum = vecHDD[(int)vecOffsets[i].m_llCurOffset];
            }

            // start changing indices for values equivalent to nMinimum
            for(int i = 0; i < (int)vecOffsets.size(); i++)
            {
                bool bKeepChanging  = true;
                for(int j = 0; j < ROWS && (true == bKeepChanging) && ((vecOffsets[i].m_llCurOffset - vecOffsets[i].m_llOffset) < ROWS); j++)
                {
                    if(RetrieveValueFromHDD(vecOffsets[i].m_llCurOffset) == nMinimum)
                        vecOffsets[i].m_llCurOffset++;
                    else // terminate correct fragment
                        bKeepChanging = false; 
                }

                if  ((vecOffsets[i].m_llCurOffset - vecOffsets[i].m_llOffset) >= ROWS && (false == vecOffsets[i].m_bChecked))
                {
                    vecOffsets[i].m_bChecked = true;
                    nFragments--;
                }
            }

            std::cout << "distinct number:" << nMinimum << '\n';
            nCount++;
        }

        std::cout << "total distinctive numbers: " << nCount;
    }

    void main()
    {
        FILE*       pf;
        std::string str;
        long        nCount          = 0;
        long        arr[ROWS]       = { 0 };
        __int64     i64Offset       = 0;
        char        pDirectoryPath[256 * 2];

        // get current location
        _getcwd(pDirectoryPath, ARRSIZE(pDirectoryPath));
        strcat_s(pDirectoryPath, FILE_NAME);
        fopen_s(&pf, pDirectoryPath, "r");
        if (pf == NULL)
            return;

        std::vector<CPair>      vecPos;
        char                    pLine[MAX_LINE];
        while (0 != fgets(pLine, MAX_LINE, pf))
        {
            arr[nCount] = atoi(pLine);
            nCount++;
            if (nCount == ROWS)
            {
                // create the offset array, save the start of each fragment
                vecOffsets.push_back(CPair(i64Offset));
                std::vector<long> vec(arr, arr + ARRSIZE(arr));
                std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

                // continue creating the HDD array, it will hold sorted fragments.
                vecHDD.insert(vecHDD.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
                i64Offset   += nCount;
                nCount      = 0;
            }
        }

        FindDistinct();
        fclose(pf);
    }
```